# Runtime Error - Do not hardcode "/data/"; use Context.getFilesDir().getPath() instead

Tags: android, sqlite

In my application i'm creating a database that would retrieve values (if stored). but while running application its showing error `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: Could not open database`.

Here's code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    // Creating Database 

    SQLiteDatabase dtbase = openOrCreateDatabase("/data/data/com.example.students/databases/ListDB", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null );
    dtbase.setVersion(1);
    dtbase.setLockingEnabled(true);
    dtbase.close();
}
```

Comment: Consider extending `SQLiteOpenHelper` to manage your databases. The error in your question title comes from lint; it's not the runtime error.

Comment: the location of the database file changes according to the mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You can access your database without giving relative path.*

Simply use DB name `ListDB` instead of using `"/data/data/com.example.students/databases/ListDB"`.

Like `openOrCreateDatabase("ListDB", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null );`

It will point the database ListDB at `/data/data/com.example.students/databases/`

---

***And yes as laalto said, you should consider extending SQLiteOpenHelper to manage your databases. Your current approach is not a good way. Read [Android SQLite Database Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) for example.***

Comment: +1: I often see users specifying a database path, while Android already knows itself where it wants to store and retrieve it.

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar +1: just one thing even if database is not created it'll automatically create one, as i used `openOrCreateDatabase`

Comment: @Androidbeginner Yes. It will create if not exists.

Comment: @Androidbeginner See updated answer. Added a link to read and implement a better solution :)